# Does the JVM JIT generate syscall instructions?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, system-calls, jit

I am wondering how does Java code make a syscall, does the JIT compiler generate syscall instructions directly, or that it just put calls to libc functions (or other basic library functions)?

Comment: You need to specify a particular JVM, such as HotSpot. That said, most will use libc calls.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about JVM that does not use libc?

Comment: Java code doesn't use `libc` directly, and there are hardware based JVMs which might not have a libc.

Comment: "doesn't use `libc` directly" means "but in the bottom line it does"? for now i don't care about  hardware based JVMs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hotspot JVM generates machine code for Java code (which doesn't support making syscalls).

All code which makes syscalls is in a native method.

So when Java wants to make a syscalls, you have to call some native code to do it for you.

There are libraries you can use to wrap native calls. E.g. JNA and JNR-FFI. This allows you call c libraries without writhing native code.